# 405 Method Not Allowed for DELETE

Tags: java, http, postman, http-delete

I'm getting a '405 Method Not Allowed' when I attempt for a DELETE without passing the resource Id which needs to be deleted.Here is my URL

```
http://localhost:8080/api/vendors/delete/1234/
```

where ideally I should have given the ID at the end of the URL like:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/vendors/delete/1234/{id}
```

I'm convinced it should be a 405 but my QA team thinks otherwise. They say it should be a 400. Can someone point out to me any resource which clearly specifies what HTTP code it should be for this scenario.

Comment: If you have that endpoint with a different method then 405 is correct. If you don't have that endpoint with a different method then it should be 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For your main question, if the *method* is `DELETE` and the path `/api/vendors/delete/1234/` is valid for other methods but not for `DELETE`, then `405 Method Not Allowed` ("A request method is not supported for the requested resource") is correct, since there is a "resource" at that path that doesn't support delete, e.g. it might support `GET` to retrieve a list of vendors.

   If there is no resource there, i.e. the method doesn't matter, then `404 Not Found` ("The requested resource could not be found") would be the correct response.
2. If the method is `DELETE`, not `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, or any of the others, you shouldn't need `.../delete/...` in the path.
3. If you're trying to delete Vendor 1234, then path should be `http://localhost:8080/api/vendor/1234` and the method should be `DELETE`. The action handler should use `/api/vendor/{id}` in the declaration.

Comment: Ah, the answer I was looking for. Actually your third point saved the day. Once I got rid of 'delete' in the URL I see a 404 for a request without an {id}  in the URL. Which is expected.. Thank you so much Andreas

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion 404 Not Found or 400 Bad Request is a good option.
Please refer to this answer as well
[HTTP Status Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454811/which-http-status-code-to-use-for-required-parameters-not-provided)