# HTTP Response for Unsuccessful Handling of Request

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

Let's say I have a REST `POST` end-point: `www.foo.com/id/X` where `X` represents a number.

My server-side pseudocode looks like this:

```
performIdLookup(int id) { 

  if ( idExists(id) ) {
     return toJson(lookup(id)) // returns 200/OK Status Code with object as JSON
  }
  else {
     return HTTP_???_error 
  }
}
```

Per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364527/http-status-code-for-bad-data), sending a `400` error doesn't seem right here since the user submitted a valid request, but the server couldn't locate it.

What's the right HTTP response here and why?

Comment: that is the right error 404

Comment: you should have 404 memorized by now - doing web development ;p

Comment: 404 is ok. by the way 500 is internal server error

Comment: @ScottSelby 500 should *not* be non-authenticated. `500 Internal Server Error`: "    A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable."

Comment: @ScottSelby Since the response is JSON, this looks like a REST API. Redirecting is not a good idea for such a scenario.

Comment: @Tichodroma - yup , missed that too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is very easy.

```
404 Not Found
```

If there is no resourece at `/id/42`, a resource can **not** be **found** for this URL.

See the [list of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error).

Comment: [404](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) `The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI` I don't understand your answer wrt to this text. Is it because there's no `resource` living at an `id` of `X`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith - you wrote " server couldn't locate it."  that is exactly what 404 is for

Comment: The server has not found anything matching the Request-UR(Resource)I(Identifier).

Answer (score 1):

Not 400 (bad request). But 404 (not found). Yes, 404 is not what we are used to watching in these cases, but you can add some custom information with response.